# disable spelling assistance in HTML for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, html, blackberry

Is there a way to disable spelling assistance in HTML input fields in BlackBerry 6/Iphone/android?
 I tried setting the
 autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="false" autocorrect="false"  spellcheck="false"
 ", but doing that unfortunately doesn't seem to disable the autocomplete .

I'm trying to do this because I want to use a custom autocompleter, but the BlackBerry autocompleter keeps getting in the way.

Thanks
Kevin
Any Ideas would be great

Answer (score 8):

Don't use "false", use "off":

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="keyword" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Adding these attributes didn't help on Blackberry device.

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing this and testing on an iPhone and all of them seem to use "off" except spellcheck needs to be "false."

Answer (score -1):

For blackberry, instead of using input type="text", you can use input type="email". Auto correct is by default off for email in blackberry.
This is specially very helpful when application is being build using sencha.