# jQuery-UI Autocomplete plugin AND Blackberry Autocompleter

Tags: jquery-ui, blackberry, jquery-mobile

I am using autocomplete jquery-ui plugin on jquery mobile framework.  This setup is working great on all mobile devices but the Blackberry platform. The watermark is showing correctly so I know javascript is enabled and working however when a user starts typing it appears that Blackberry is over-riding and showing its own autocomplete/fill text options, when a user selects the jquery plugin is not firing.

On a desktop browser I can paste text and it works fine.  It appears to be related to Blackberry mobile devices only.

Ideas on how to disable through code Blackberry autofill functionality?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `autocomplete="off"` attribute on the input tag:

```
<input autocomplete="off" .../>
```

*Source: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript*

Comment: This didn't have any impact on the Blackberry device (and its built in autocomplete functionality)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<input autocomplete="off" .../>
```

But it isn't working for (some?) BlackBerry devices. They ignore the atribute. A possible workaround/hack is to set the input-type to "email", since they never have autocorrect on bb's.

Via: [disable spelling assistance in HTML for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380972/disable-spelling-assistance-in-html-for-mobile-devices)